# nginx and public subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm very new in nginx server configuration. I have a problem serving files under subdirectories on public directory.

Example, files under; rails_app/public/uploads/client/2/image/7/ directory or rails_app/public/picture/ directory are not served
but i have no problems with: rails_app/public/webcam.swf

is like somehow subdirectories are not serve.

my production.rb file

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

only if i set serve_static_assets to true i have no problems

my nginx configuration:

```
upstream thin {
  server '127.0.0.1:3000';
  server '127.0.0.1:3001';
  server '127.0.0.1:3002';
  server '127.0.0.1:3003';
  server '127.0.0.1:3004';
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/user/appname/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    root /home/user/appname/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://thin;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

can you help me with this configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your config is pretty standard.  What's in your error log when you make a failing request?

Comment: here i what i got: [21/Feb/2013:04:39:11 +0400] "GET /pictures/20-02-2013-09-55-37.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 446 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.69 Safari/537.17"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your `location /` block is catching your dynamic requests as well as your non-asset static requests.  Try this config (note the try_files line):

```
server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/user/appname/public;
  try_files $uri @app;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    root /home/user/appname/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://thin;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```